# Epivally SXC 1080 Modem

Tags: 11.10, modem

I have `Tata Epivally SXC 1080 1 X USB Modem`. I want to use it with Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit OS. what steps should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple in Ubuntu, insert the modem, next go to network manager icon on top panel, click on it, select "Edit Connections" below drop down menu, select "Mobile Broadband" tab, click "Add" then "Continue" Select Country "India", here U find Tata Indicom, selec appropriate device of Your's,